# Событие создания элемента инфоблока

Tags: битрикс

Какое событие можно использовать для создания элемента инфоблока на страницах сайта, а не в административном разделе? `OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd`, почему-то, не работает. Нужно повесить на это событие авторегистрацию пользователя.

Comment: какая версия Битрикс? если последняя, стоит надстройка в модуле "Поддержка старых событий"?

Comment: и лучше вешай на событие OnAfterIBlockElementAdd, т.е. после добавление элемента

Comment: Версия 15.5.10.

Answer (score 1):

попробую ответить, разницы нет, откуда добавляется элемент, обработчик висит на методе CIBlockElement::Add, но советую использовать событие OnAfterIBlockElementAdd, так как он выполнится только после добавления эл-а, а то OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd может сработать и при ошибке добавления, что мне кажется будет не очень хорошо.

Попробуй вставь код в init.php

```
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd", Array("Stackoverflow", "OnAfterIBlockElementAddHandler"));

class Stackoverflow
{
     // создаем обработчик события "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd"
     function OnAfterIBlockElementAddHandler(&$arFields)
    {
         CUser::Add(array(
              "NAME"              => "Тест",
              "LAST_NAME"         => "Тестов",
              "EMAIL"             => "test@stackoverflow.com",
              "LOGIN"             => "testtest",
              "LID"               => "ru",
              "ACTIVE"            => "Y",
              "PASSWORD"          => "123456aBc!",
              "CONFIRM_PASSWORD"  => "123456aBc!",
         ));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Может быть, дело в том, что на сайте используется какой-то самописный компонент... Я не увидел в нем вызова `CIBlockElement::Add`, есть только конструкция типа `$el = new CIBlockElement;`. Выполняет те же действия?

Comment: ну создается объект класса CIBlockElement, $el->Add ниже есть?

Comment: может у тебя в CUser::Add не все обязательные поля передаются? и поэтому юзер не добавляется

Comment: попробуй код выше просто поставить в init.php и проверить

Comment: там `Add` вообще нет в файле... Странно тогда, но в раздел `Заказы` в магазине запись добавляется...

Comment: так создается заказ?) или добавляется элемент в инфоблок

Comment: если заказ, то нужно вешать на событие OnOrderAdd или OnOrderSave

Comment: да, видиимо, перепутал заказ и элемент инфоблока. Элемент на том этапе еще не создается, создается заказ. Я использую такой код для реакции на событие:

`AddEventHandler('sale', 'OnOrderAdd', ['OnOrderAddHandler']);
function OnOrderAddHandler(&$ID, &$arFields) {
  var_dump($arFields, true); die();
}`

Но ничего не происходит. По идее, как я понимаю, должна вывестись белая страница с дампом `arFields`. Ваш код с добавлением пользователя тоже не работает.

Comment: так как используется функция, нужно во втором параметре передавать название функции, а не массив, вот так:`AddEventHandler('sale', 'OnOrderAdd', 'OnOrderAddHandler');`

Comment: Все равно не хочет работать.(

Comment: код в `init.php`? а у тебя там не ajax какой-нибудь? тогда ты `die()` и не заметишь. Вместо `die()`, либо `AddMessage2Log()` используй, либо добавляй юзера, как выше писал

Comment: и кстати, попробуй повесь событие на `OnOrderSave`, на счет `OnOrderAdd` какую-то траблу припоминаю